# Vue- variables inside event bus are not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, event-bus

I created global event bus

```
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue()
```

In 'component 2' clicking on the button, emitted the event then navigating to 'component 1'

```
this.$eventHub.$emit('deleted')
```

In another 'component 1' i am trying to use it

```
data: function () {
  return {
    testVariable : true
  }
},
beforeMount () {
  var self = this
  this.$eventHub.$on('deleted', function () {
    console.log("executed")
    self.testVariable = false
  })
}
```

In the template section i used `{{testVariable}}`, it's always displaying true. Why it is not reactive? what did i miss?

Comment: is `console.log("executed")` executed ?

Comment: yes it is printed.

Comment: hmm weird. it worked for me https://codesandbox.io/s/z6wv7y7rz4

Comment: If i add setTimeOut in the component 2 it is working. But how it like that? I navigated from component 2 to component 1, after navigated in the next line i used $emit still not working what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried creating router?

Comment: I think you misunderstood how the event works. The event listener has to exist when the event is emitted. Which means component 1 and component 2 has to exist at the same time.

Comment: Since you want to navigate from 1 route to another, you can either 1) store the shared state in Vuex, 2) pass the boolean value through a url param for e.g. `url?testVariable=true`